# Share cookie .net Core 3 and Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

Trying to share auth cookie by following the microsoft docs here: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Heres my Startup.vb from the older Webforms project.

```
  <Assembly: OwinStartup("Me", GetType(Startup))>
    Public Class Startup
       Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)

        Dim opt = New CookieAuthenticationOptions
        opt.AuthenticationType = "Identity.Application"
        opt.CookieName = ".SSO"
        opt.LoginPath = New PathString("/Login.aspx")
        opt.CookieDomain = "localhost"
        opt.CookieHttpOnly = False
        opt.CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest
        Dim proc = DataProtectionProvider.Create(New DirectoryInfo("c:\Temp\DataKeys"), Function(s) s.SetApplicationName("MyApp")).CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2")
        Dim shim = New DataProtectorShim(proc)

        opt.CookieManager = New ChunkingCookieManager()
        opt.TicketDataFormat = New AspNetTicketDataFormat(shim)
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(opt)

    End Sub

End Class
```

And here is the startup for .net core 3 app.

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Environment = env;
    }
    public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(o =>
        {
            o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 2000 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

        services.AddSingleton<IJwtHandler, JwtHandler>();
        services.Configure<TokenSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Token"));
        services.AddSingleton<IWebHostEnvironment>(Environment);

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddFileReaderService();

        services.AddTelerikBlazor();
        services.AddSweetAlert2();


        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        services.Configure<AnimateOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Animation = Animations.Fade;
            options.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
        });


        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp\DataKeys"))
            .SetApplicationName("MyApp");

        services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application")
        .AddCookie("Identity.Application", options =>
        {
            options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
            {
                Domain = "localhost",
                Name = ".SSO",
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                HttpOnly= false,
                SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
                IsEssential = true
            };
        });


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {



        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

I login to the legacy Webforms app, everything works fine. I try to navigate to the .net core 3 app, and it says I'm not authenticated, it does pass the cookie. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show your `startup` *class* and `ConfigureServices` method

Comment: Did you end up figuring it out? I'm in the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did end up figuring this out for the most part.

On the .net Core 3 app, you can remove the 'DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration()' call if you plan on generating the keys from the .net core app.

```
     var proc = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration["SSO:KeyLocation"].ToString()), (builder) => { builder.SetApplicationName("MyApp").ProtectKeysWithDpapi().DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration(); })
        .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2");

            services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application")
            .AddCookie("Identity.Application", options =>
            {
                options.TicketDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(proc);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
                {
                    Domain = Configuration["SSO:Domain"].ToString(),
                    Name = ".SSO",
                    SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None,
                    IsEssential = true,
                };

            });
```

And on the .Net Framework app, You can remove 'ProtectKeysWithDpapi()', if the web apps are not running under the same Service account for the app pools.

Also, you need to make sure you have this version of nuget package installed on both apps,
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection v3.1.3

```
Dim opt = New CookieAuthenticationOptions
opt.AuthenticationType = "Identity.Application"
opt.CookieName = ".SSO"
opt.LoginPath = New PathString("/Login.aspx")
opt.CookieDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SSODomain")
opt.SlidingExpiration = True

Dim proc = DataProtectionProvider.Create(New DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SSOKeyLocation")), Function(s) s.SetApplicationName("MyApp").SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(9000)).ProtectKeysWithDpapi()).CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2")

Dim shim = New DataProtectorShim(proc)

opt.TicketDataFormat = New AspNetTicketDataFormat(shim)

app.UseCookieAuthentication(opt)
```

For localhost development/testing, just set the domain to 'localhost'